# Preventing an duplicate ajax events in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-interface

What is a good way to block until a previous ajax event is completed?

I followed [How can you make a vote-up-down button like in Stackoverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719194/how-can-you-make-a-vote-up-down-button-like-in-stackoverflow) but if I click the button fast enough, it'll send multiple (and maybe inconsistent) events to the server.  How do I make it so it'll forcethe user to wait before another click can be registered?

Edit:  I also do not want it to block globally - just for that button/item. Do I'll need to maintain a hash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well since I wrote that I guess I might as well answer this too ;)

The 'common' way of doing this is by having an indicator variable that the request is in progress and updating it accordingly before/after everything happens. For my code in that question, you would edit it as follows:

Outside of the click function, add this:

```
var voting = false; // not initially voting
```

Inside the click function, at the very top, add this:

```
if(voting) return false; // if voting, return
voting = true; // if not, set voting to true
```

Inside of both post callbacks, add this:

```
voting = false; // done voting, set back to false
```

If you want to maintain an indicator on a per-question/answer/item basis, you could do this:

First, replace this code:

```
var id = $(this).parents('div.answer').attr('id').split('_')[1];
```

With this:

```
var parent = $(this).parents('div.answer'); // get the parent div
if(parent.data('voting')) return false; // if voting, return
parent.data('voting', true); // if not, update the marker
var id = parent.attr('id').split('_')[1]; // get the id
```

Then inside both post callbacks, add this:

```
parent.data('voting', false); // done voting, set back to false
```

In this case we'd be using jQuery's [data](http://docs.jquery.com/Core) to store the voting status of a particular question/answer/item inside the containing DIV and updating it accordingly whenever something happens.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Bind the event once using [jQuery.fn.one](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/one#typedatafn) then bind it again in the callback function

```
myFunc = function() {
   $.post(url, data, function(data){
      $('#button').one('click', myFunc)
   }
};

$('#button').one('click', myFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the begin and end AJAX events to set a global var stating busy until the request is complete. Show a message that the action is executing to advise the user too.

Jquery has a load of functions to help if it suits your app:

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

Comment: I also do not want it to block globally - just for that button.  I'll need to maintain a hash?