# ASP.Net Ajax Stackoverflow style Vote Button

Tags: asp.net-ajax, stack-overflow

I've been looking to implement a StackOverflow style voting system on my ASP.NET site using ASP.Net Ajax. I've looked at the controls in the toolkit and generally been very impressed but nothing quite suits my needs. I like the [Rating](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Rating/Rating.aspx) control, but I'd rather use Up/Down voting instead of a vote out of 5. The [ToggleButton](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ToggleButton/ToggleButton.aspx) is also close to what I want but still slightly different.

I've seen [the post about how to do this in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719194/how-can-you-make-a-vote-up-down-button-like-in-stackoverflow) and really liked it but before I reimplement the whole thing in .Net I'd like to know if someone's already done the work.

Does anyone know of a control that implements SO-like behaviour in ASP.Net Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

I guess my thing is why couldn't you just create a user control with image buttons and re-use it across your site ?
Seems simple enough.  Could be two image buttons place in a usser control, you can even build in some js to handle hover overs and such.  Just a thought.

Comment: While this is always an option, the point is that I don't want to recreate this functionality if it already exists.