# HTML incrementing voting system

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm pretty new to html, I am trying to show a value on my web page that increments when a button is pressed.

Here is my code:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
     var likesSD = 0;
     var dislikesSD= 0;
</script>
    <button class="like" onclick="likes++">I like!</button>
<script>document.write(likesSD);</script>
```

The value on the screen does not change when the button is pushed.  Is there a way I can do that without using a database?

Comment: Few things: There is no `likes` variable. You shouldn't use `document.write`. This will lose the *likes* on page load. The user won't see likes being incremented because it's only written to the page on load.

Comment: Already mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719194/how-can-you-make-a-vote-up-down-button-like-in-stackoverflow).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<div id="likes"></div>

<script type ="text/javascript">
    var likes = 0;

    function IncreaseLikes()
    {
        likes++;
        document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML = likes;
    }
</script>

<input type="button" class="like" onclick="IncreaseLikes()" value="I like!" />
```

- Use some element to hold the value, It's not nice to use `document.write()`;
- I have changed your button to `input type="button"`;
- Whithout database the information will be lost on page refresh. You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)(supported in all modern browsers) in order to keep the value saved, but only in the browser. Still not valid for a real votting pool.

Comment: You declared the variable `likesSD` but you are incrementing `likes`.

Comment: there is no variable `likes`. Did you mean `likesSD++` and `...innerHTML = likesSD`?

Comment: document.getElementById("likes") will not work if you use class="like" instead of id="like"

Comment: @osi `likes` is the `id` of the `div`. Please read carefully.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown you are totally right, sorry to overlooked that. You might want to move all the html together for clearer reading

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a function that increments your like / dislike counter and then writes it to the document. Then map that function to the onclick event of your button:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
     var likesSD = 0;
     var dislikesSD= 0;

     function like() {
         likesSD++;
         document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML = likesSD;
     }
</script>
    <button class="like" onclick="like()">I like!</button>
    <div id="likes"></div>
```

Comment: This won't work. `document.write` will replace the page body, including the markup for the `<button>`

Comment: Really? I thought document.write just writes to the end of the html document?

Comment: It's context-based, but in the context above that is what will happen